# Convert datetime to specific format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to convert a datetime to a specific format. The conversion should result in a variable of type datetime and not char or varchar. How do I do this in SQL server 2000, 2005 and 2008 ?

```
select CONVERT(varchar(30),getdate(),120)
```

I tried this, but it gives me a string. I want a datetime without the milli-seconds. SS 2012 has an option for this, but not previous versions.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/21/sql-server-display-datetime-in-specific-format-sql-in-sixty-seconds-033-video/

Comment: This gices you a bunch of built in (and calculated) date formats, along with examples of each: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have it both ways ... a variable of type "datetime" is defined as:

```
Defines a date that is combined with a time of day 
with fractional seconds that is based on a 24-hour clock
```

You can CONVERT and DISPLAY in whatever format you choose, but the datetime data type will always have the milliseconds, even if you set them to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the milliseconds from the datetime like this:

```
DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, date), date) > '2013-11-18 03:21:52'
```

Also check [SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

or may be try like this to remove the millisecond part:-

```
declare @str datetime
set @str = '2013-11-18 17:24:05.784'
select convert(datetime, convert(char(19), @str, 126))
```

Comment: did not work for me. I tried select  DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -DATEPART(MILLISECOND, getdate()), getdate()) and got milliseconds in the result.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But, the edited code also shows millisecond. I guess BWS is right. No matter what you do, SQL server will add a millisecond part .000 to a datetime. You can't have it both ways

Comment: But, I am glad that i learned how to remove the milliseconds part. It could be useful in the future.

Comment: @blasto:- Yes that is true. I am just trying to make a point that you can remove the millisecond partt from the datetime